# Secure Webmin with Apache VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm trying to setup my [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) instance to the address https://webmin.example.com but I'm getting an internal server error (500). Any ideas why?

Here's my Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName webmin.example.com
    ServerAlias webmin.example.com

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:10000/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:10000/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's contents of the log file:

```
[ssl:error] [pid 21593] [remote 127.0.0.1:10000] AH01961: SSL Proxy requested for webmin.example.com:443 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
[proxy:error] [pid 21593] AH00961: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for 127.0.0.1:10000 (127.0.0.1)
```

Comment: what does server log say?

Comment: Sorry @Jakuje, should have included that - added now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are proxying https request, you need to enable SSL proxy

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName webmin.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:10000/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:10000/

</VirtualHost>
```

You also need to enable some modules:

- mod_ssl
- mod_proxy
- mod_proxy_http

If your ServerAlias is the same as your servername it become useless, so you can remove it

You can remove this part, by default you will have access granted:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

If you are using a self signed certificate, you need to remove SSL verification:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
```

instead of

```
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
```

more info here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html

Comment: That still gives me an Error in my log file:

AH01084: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:10000 (127.0.0.1)

AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /
AH01097: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:10000 (127.0.0.1) from 86.190.204.108 ()

Comment: Are you using a self signed certificate ?

Comment: Yes @Friggiz, I am.

Comment: Ok, i edited my answer for this case

Comment: Np, i am happy it helped you ^_^